# How to filter collection by data in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have collection of objects stored in a variable '$articles'. Each article has 1-3 categories. These categories can be accessed through the variable '$catIDs' (see below). I also have a collection of 1-3 categories stored in a variable '$categoryChoice'. These are the categories chosen by a user.

I only want to display the articles that have one or more of the categories stored in the variable '$categoryChoice'. I'm almost there but I don't know how to link '$catIDs' with each specific article and then match them with '$categoryChoice' IDs.

I've look in the docs [HERE](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) and [HERE](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections), but I'm lost! (Laravel 5)

Database tables: 'articles' (id, title, etc...) 'categories' (id, name) 'article_category' (article_id, category_id)

My ArticlesController:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
$lat = $request->get('lat');
$lng = $request->get('lng');
//  THIS GETS THE USER DEFINED CATEGORY CHOICES
$categoryChoice = $request->get('categoryList');
$distance = 1;

$query = Article::getByDistance($lat, $lng, $distance);
    if(empty($query)) 
    {
        return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
    }

$ids = [];

    //Extracts the article/store id's
foreach($query as $q)
{
      array_push($ids, $q->id);
}

$articles = Article::find($ids);

$catIDs = [];

foreach ($articles as $article)
{

    array_push($catIDs, $article->categories->lists('id'));

}

// if $categoryChoice is equal to $catIDs only show those articles.


    return view('articles.index', compact('categories', 'days'))->withArticles($articles);

}
```

Here's the relevant parts of my Article Model:

```
public function categories()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->withTimestamps();
}
public static function getByDistance($lat, $lng, $distance)
{
 $results = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat .') ) * sin( radians(lat) ) ) ) AS distance FROM articles HAVING distance < ' . $distance . ' ORDER BY distance') );
 return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your article model, you should have the relationship set up

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

Then you can query the relationship:

```
$articles = Article::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($categoryChoice) {    
    $query->whereIn('categories.id', $categoryChoice);    
})->get();
```

You've also got a query in there for distance. getByDistance sounds like a query scope. If you change that method to return the query (don't `get()` the results, just return the `$query` object you can chain the methods. If you want to use the laravel naming convention you can call it `scopeDistance($lat, $lng, $distance)` and reference it as `distance`

Then your index method simplifies to:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $lat = $request->get('lat');
    $lng = $request->get('lng');
    $distance = 1;

    //  THIS GETS THE USER DEFINED CATEGORY CHOICES
    $categoryChoice = $request->get('categoryList');

    $query = Article::distance($lat, $lng, $distance)
        ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($categoryChoice) {    
            $query->whereIn('categories.id', $categoryChoice);    
        })->get();


    if(count($articles) == 0) 
    {
        return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
    }

    return view('articles.index', compact('categories', 'articles'));

}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. I already have that r/ship set up in my article model. When I tried your code I got this error: 'Undefined variable: categoryChoice'. I don't know why. I put your code just above my final line.

Comment: Oh, I missed a use statement. There is a change in scope because of the callback. I edited my answer.

Comment: That's great. It works, but...It means it the getByDistance is no longer working. I had a collection of articles stored in $articles that was limited by distance. Now this lists all articles that have certain categories bu doesn't limit them to distance. There must be a way to join the two? sorry for all the questions!

Comment: There was a lot going on in your code sample! I'll do another edit.

Comment: Wow thanks so much. I've added in what getByDistance was above. I changed the function name to scopeDistance and called the variable $query that returns $query, is that right? I now get this error: ErrorException in Article.php line 48:
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string. I will keep trying to solve myself but I thought I'd share. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, it's because you're doing a raw query in there. You've changed scope a few times you should make a new ticket for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97234/discussion-between-thomas-jaunism-and-zoe-blair).

Comment: Changed it to this function https://gist.github.com/stevenmaguire/3ada3f73f1ad03356cf5 and added this to my controller      $articles = $query;   
and now it works. Thanks for going above and beyond